# Javascript refactor if condition function

Tags: javascript

I have this function

```
    const rank = (totalPoints, pointsRank) => {
    if (totalPoints <= pointsRank[0]) {
        return ({
            rank: 1,
            pointsLeftForNextRank: (pointsRank[1] - totalPoints)
        })
    } else if (totalPoints >= pointsRank[1] && totalPoints < pointsRank[2]) {
        return ({
            rank: 2,
            pointsLeftForNextRank: (pointsRank[2] - totalPoints)
        })
    } else if (totalPoints >= pointsRank[2] && totalPoints < pointsRank[3]) {
        return ({
            rank: 3,
            pointsLeftForNextRank: (pointsRank[3] - totalPoints)
        })
    } else if (totalPoints >= pointsRank[3] && totalPoints < pointsRank[4]) {
        return ({
            rank: 4,
            pointsLeftForNextRank: (pointsRank[4] - totalPoints)
        })
    } else if (totalPoints >= pointsRank[4] && totalPoints < pointsRank[5]) {
        return ({
            rank: 5,
            pointsLeftForNextRank: (pointsRank[5] - totalPoints)
        })
    } else if (totalPoints >= pointsRank[5] && totalPoints < pointsRank[6]) {
        return ({
            rank: 6,
            pointsLeftForNextRank: (pointsRank[6] - totalPoints)
        })
    } else if (totalPoints >= pointsRank[6]) {
        return ({
            rank: 7,
            pointsLeftForNextRank: 0
        })
    }
}
module.exports = rank
```

and I call it like this

```
            let pointsRank = [150, 500, 1000, 2000, 3500, 5000, 5500]
            let totalPoints = 1200
            rank(totalPoints, pointsRank)
```

output

```
{ rank: 3, pointsLeftForNextRank: 600 }
```

how can I improve this function? I feel like that I wrote a lot of code which can be refactored into something smaller
like a small amount of code that does the same functionality
also, I need to know if am violating any of the SOLID principles

Comment: You can use `loop (for/while)` with `break` to achieve the same

Comment: This question lacks any indication of what the code is intended to achieve. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically we search for the most close number from array where our number belongs. After we find the min value, we take the index of it and add 1, because the rank starts from 1

```js
//rank 1 : 150 - 500
//rank 2 : 500 - 1000
//rank 3 : 1000 - 2000
//rank 4 : 2000 - 3500
//rank 5 : 3500 - 5000
//rank 6 : 5000 - 5500

let pointsRank = [150, 500, 1000, 2000, 3500, 5000, 5500]

function rank(pointsRank, score) {
  var closest = pointsRank.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return (Math.abs(curr - score) < Math.abs(prev - score) ? curr : prev);
  });
  var rank = pointsRank.indexOf(closest) + 1; // cuz starts from 0 and we don't have rank 0
  console.log("min range: " + closest +
    " | our score: " + score +
    " | max range: " + pointsRank[rank])

  return {
    rank: rank,
    pointsLeftForNextRank: (pointsRank[rank] - score)
  }

}

const test1 = rank(pointsRank, 1200);
const test2 = rank(pointsRank, 2000);
const test3 = rank(pointsRank, 3700);

console.log(test1);
console.log(test2);
console.log(test3);
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].